# UnityMainThreadDispatcher does not exist in current context error

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

UnityMainThreadDispatcher does not exist in current context error
this is the error begin shown to me in the code i think I forgot to include a library(that i dont know)

i tried using multithreading to solve a performance error while traversing an array of obstacle on terrain and spawning other empty game object on them

here is the code that i am using

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


public class levelmovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]float speed;
    Rigidbody rb;

    [SerializeField] GameObject objectToInstantiate;
    public int maxThreads = 4; // Adjust as needed based on CPU cores
    Terrain terrain;
    private void Start()
    {
        terrain = GetComponent<Terrain>();
        if (terrain == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No active terrain found!");
            return;
        }

        TreeInstance[] treeInstances = terrain.terrainData.treeInstances;
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        // Divide tree instances into batches (optional for large datasets)
        int batchSize = Mathf.CeilToInt(treeInstances.Length / (float)maxThreads);
        for (int i = 0; i < treeInstances.Length; i += batchSize)
        {
            int endIndex = Mathf.Min(i + batchSize, treeInstances.Length);
            TreeInstance[] batch = new TreeInstance[endIndex - i];
            Array.Copy(treeInstances, i, batch, 0, batch.Length);

            // Create a Task for each batch
            tasks.Add(PlaceTreesAsync(batch));
        }

        // Wait for all tasks to complete (optional)
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); // Comment out for parallel execution

        Debug.Log("Tree placement completed.");
    }

    private async Task PlaceTreesAsync(TreeInstance[] batch)
    {
        foreach (TreeInstance treeInst`your text`ance in batch)
        {
            Vector3 worldPosition = Vector3.Scale(treeInstance.position, terrain.terrainData.size) + terrain.transform.position;

            // Use UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Post for safe object creation
            await UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Post(() =>
            {
                Instantiate(objectToInstantiate, worldPosition, Quaternion.identity, transform);
            });
        }
    }
```